# scope array in angularjs is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am building an angularjs app but I have an issue with $scope var.

I have the following definition:

```
$scope.data = {
        object: {
          id: undefined,
          name: undefined,
          category:
          {
            id: undefined,
            name: undefined
          },
          description: undefined,
          featured: 1,
          seassons: undefined
        }, 
        progress: 0,
        emptyResponse : false
    };
```

The issue is that when I tried to set the property $scope.data.object.name I get the following error in console: TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined.
Is there any way to initialize the arrays inside $scope var? I tried

```
$scope.data.object = []
```

which works, but just in the scope of that function, and also if I call that function again I will lose the previous data.
Is there any way to do this? Another way to do it works, is if I set the value of that property from the view through ng-model, but in some cases I need to do some logic in my controller.

The controller is correctly defined

```
function VideoCreateController($scope,....)
```

Full controller, the method that is failing is IsValid, but also if I execute Create function without completing some fields in the view (when I tried to assign those values I get undefined)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('naut')
        .controller('VideoCreateController', VideoCreateController);

    function VideoCreateController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $state, SessionService, ProgramFactory,  SeassonFactory, VideoFactory, CategoryFactory, SubcategoryFactory, $filter, ngTableParams, SweetAlert, $routeParams, $translate){
        var vm = this;

    $rootScope.baseurl = "#/app/Video/";
    $scope.data = {
        object: {
          id: undefined,
          name: undefined,
          category:
          {
            id: undefined,
            name: undefined
          },
          description: undefined,
          featured: 1,
          belongtoprogram: false,
          isfeatured: false,
          adv: false,
          images: undefined,
          preview: undefined,
          categories: undefined,
          subcategories: undefined,
          programs: undefined,
          episode: undefined,
          seassons: undefined
        }, 
        progress: 0,
        videosubmitted: false,
        uploading: false,
        errorMessage: undefined,
        error: false,
        emptyResponse : false
    };

    $scope.image = null;
    $scope.imageFileName = '';

    $scope.uploadme = {};
    $scope.uploadme.src = '';

    var obj = [];
    $scope.data.object = obj;
    $scope.GetInformation = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('LOAD');
     CategoryFactory.GetAll()
          .then(function(response){
              ProgramFactory.GetAll()
                .then(function(programresponse){
              if (response.success && programresponse.success) {
                  $scope.data.object.categories = response.data;
                  $scope.data.object.subcategories = null;
                  $scope.data.object.programs = programresponse.data;
                  $scope.data.object.seassons = null;
                  console.log($scope.data.object);
              }
              else if(response.code == "ERROR__NOT_AUTHORIZED")
              {
                $location.path('/NotAuthorized');
              }
              else
              {
                  $scope.data.error = true;
                  $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;
              }
              $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
          }, function(response){
                if (response == null) {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = "ERROR__SERVER_NON_WORKING";
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = response.Message;    
                }
                $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
            });
            });
    }

    $scope.GetSubcategories = function(id) {
    $rootScope.$emit('LOAD');
     SubcategoryFactory.GetAll(id)
          .then(function(response){
              console.log(response);
              if (response.success) {

                  $scope.data.object.subcategories = response.data;
                  console.log($scope.data.object);
              }
              else if(response.code == "ERROR__NOT_AUTHORIZED")
              {
                $location.path('/NotAuthorized');
              }
              else
              {
                  $scope.data.error = true;
                  $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;
              }
              $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
          }, function(response){
                if (response == null) {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = "ERROR__SERVER_NON_WORKING";
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = response.Message;    
                }
                $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
            });
    }

    $scope.GetSeassons = function(id) {
    $rootScope.$emit('LOAD');
     SeassonFactory.GetAll(id)
          .then(function(response){
              console.log(response);
              if (response.success) {

                  $scope.data.object.seassons = response.data;
              }
              else if(response.code == "ERROR__NOT_AUTHORIZED")
              {
                $location.path('/NotAuthorized');
              }
              else
              {
                  $scope.data.error = true;
                  $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;
              }
              $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
          }, function(response){
                if (response == null) {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = "ERROR__SERVER_NON_WORKING";
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.data.error = true;
                    $scope.data.errorMessage = response.Message;    
                }
                $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
            });
    }

    $scope.IsValid = function() {
      var valid = true;
      if(!$scope.data.object.name)
        valid = false;
      if(!$scope.data.object.description)
        valid = false;
      if(!$scope.data.object.subcategory)
        valid = false;
      if($scope.data.object.belongtoprogram && !$scope.data.object.episode && !$scope.data.object.seasson)
        valid = false;
      return valid;
    }

    $scope.Create = function(isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
        $rootScope.$emit('LOAD');
        var params = {
          id: $scope.data.object.id,
          name: $scope.data.object.name,
          preview: $scope.data.object.preview,
          adv: $scope.data.object.adv,
          featured: $scope.data.object.featured,
          description: $scope.data.object.description,
          episode: $scope.data.object.episode,
          subcategory: 
          {
            id: $scope.data.object.subcategory.id
          },
          seasson: 
          {
            id: $scope.data.object.seasson !== undefined ? $scope.data.object.seasson.id : null
          }
        };

        if(!$scope.data.object.isfeatured)
          params.featured = 0;

        VideoFactory.Create(params).then(function(response){
          if (response.success) {
            $state.go('app.video_index');
          }
          else
          {
            $scope.data.error =  true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;
          }
          $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
        }, function(response){
          if (response == null) {
            $scope.data.error = true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = "ERROR__SERVER_NON_WORKING";
          }
          else
          {
            $scope.data.error = true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;    
          }
          $rootScope.$emit('UNLOAD');
        });
      };

      }

      $scope.selected = function(image)
      {
        $scope.data.object.preview = image.source;
      }

      var callback = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.data.progress = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);  
        });
      };
      $scope.reset = function()
      {

        $scope.data.object.id = undefined;
        $scope.data.object.images = undefined;
        $scope.data.object.source = undefined;
        $scope.data.object.preview = undefined;
        $scope.data.object.description = undefined;
        $scope.data.videosubmitted = false;
        $scope.data.object.name = undefined;
        $scope.data.uploading = false;

      };

      $scope.upload = function(item) {
        $scope.data.videosubmitted = true;
        $scope.data.object.name = item.name.substr(0, item.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
        $scope.data.uploading = true;
        var params = {
          files: item
        };
        VideoFactory.Save(params, callback).then(function(response){
          response = JSON.parse(response);
          $scope.data.uploading = false;
          if (response.success) {
            $scope.data.object.id = response.data.id;
            $scope.data.object.images = response.data.images;
            $scope.data.object.source = response.data.source;
            $scope.data.object.preview = response.data.preview;
          }
          else
          {
            $scope.data.error =  true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;
          }

        }, function(response){
          if (response == null) {
            $scope.data.error = true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = "ERROR__SERVER_NON_WORKING";
          }
          else
          {
            $scope.data.error = true;
            $scope.data.errorMessage = response.code;    
          }
          $scope.data.uploading = false;
        });
      }

      $scope.GetInformation();
  }
})();
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="VideoCreateController as controller" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="queueLimit, customFilter">
    <a ng-href="{{baseurl}}Index" class="mr btn btn-labeled btn-default">
               <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
               </span><span translate="PAGE.BACK" class="nopadding"></span></a>
   <div class="app-view-header">
   <span translate="PAGE.CREATE" class="nopadding"></span><small><span translate="MODULES.VIDEO.A-VIDEO" class="nopadding"></span></small>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h1><span translate="MODULES.VIDEO.CREATE" class="nopadding"></span></h1></div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <form role="form" name="data" class="mb-lg" ng-submit="Create(data.$valid)" novalidate>
                    <div class="row" ng-show="data.error">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="alert ng-isolate-scope alert-danger alert-dismissable" ng-class="['alert-' + (type || 'warning'), closeable ? 'alert-dismissable' : null]" role="alert" type="danger">
                        <div>
                          <span class="ng-binding ng-scope"><span translate="ERROR.{{data.errorMessage}}" class="nopadding"></span></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row" ng-show="!data.videosubmitted">
                        <div class="col-md-10 no-padding-right">
                            <div class="dropzone" id="dropbox" callback-fn="upload(video)" file-dropzone="[video/mp4, video/3gpp,   video/quicktime, video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv]"
                            file="image" file-name="imageFileName" data-max-file-size="3000">
                                <span translate="MODULES.VIDEO.DROPVIDEO"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 upload-btn no-padding-left">
                            <label class="upload-search btn btn-primary  no-padding">
                            <div>
                                <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this.files[0])"/>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                <span translate="COMMON.FILESEARCH"></span>
                            </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="video-data" ng-show="data.videosubmitted">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="row margin-bottom-small">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="COMMON.NAME"></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input id="name" ng-model="data.object.name" type="text" required ng-class="{ 'has-error' : data.object.name.$invalid && !data.object.name.$pristine }" ng-minlength="2" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-small">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.CATEGORY.CATEGORY"></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <ui-select ng-model="data.object.category" ng-change="GetSubcategories(data.object.category.id)" class="text-left">
                                           <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a category...">{{data.object.category.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                           <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data.object.categories">
                                              <span ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
                                           </ui-select-choices>
                                        </ui-select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.SUBCATEGORY.SUBCATEGORY"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <ui-select ng-model="data.object.subcategory" class="text-left">
                                   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a category...">{{data.object.subcategory.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data.object.subcategories">
                                      <span ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
                                   </ui-select-choices>
                                </ui-select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="checkbox c-checkbox pull-left mt0">
                            <label class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.object.belongtoprogram" id="belongtoprogram" value="" />
                                <span class="fa fa-check checkbox-margin"></span><label for="belongtoprogram" class="nopadding" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.INPROGRAM"></label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-small" ng-show="data.object.belongtoprogram">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.PROGRAM.PROGRAM"></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <ui-select ng-model="data.object.program" ng-change="GetSeassons(data.object.program.id)" class="text-left">
                                           <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a program...">{{data.object.program.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                           <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data.object.programs">
                                              <span ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
                                           </ui-select-choices>
                                        </ui-select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.SEASSON.SEASSON"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <ui-select ng-model="data.object.seasson" class="text-left">
                                   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a seasson...">{{data.object.seasson.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data.object.seassons">
                                      <span ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
                                   </ui-select-choices>
                                </ui-select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.EPISODE"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input ng-model="data.object.episode" type="number" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : data.object.episode.$invalid && !data.object.episode.$pristine }" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="3" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-small">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-12 control-label" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.DESCRIPTION"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div text-angular="" ng-model="data.object.description" name="data.object.description" class="btn-group-small"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="checkbox c-checkbox pull-left mt0">
                            <label class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.object.adv" id="adv" value="" />
                                <span class="fa fa-check checkbox-margin"></span><label for="adv" class="nopadding" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.ADVERTISEMENT"></label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="checkbox c-checkbox pull-left mt0">
                            <label class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.object.isfeatured" id="isfeatured" value="" />
                                <span class="fa fa-check checkbox-margin"></span><label for="isfeatured" class="nopadding" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.FEATURED"></label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-small" ng-show="data.object.isfeatured">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate="MODULES.VIDEO.ORDER"></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input ng-model="data.object.featured" type="number" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : data.object.featured.$invalid && !data.object.featured.$pristine }" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div ng-show="data.uploading">
                                    <progressbar value="data.progress" class="progress-striped active">{{data.progress}}%</progressbar>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" ng-show="data.object.preview">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <img class="img-responsive center" src="/app/videos/{{data.object.source}}/screenshots/{{data.object.preview}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div ng-show="data.object.images != null">
                                    <h5 class="page-header"><span translate="MODULES.VIDEO.SELECT-PREVIEW"></span></h5>
                                    <div ng-repeat="image in data.object.images" class="col-lg-3">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail" ng-class="{ 'preview-selected': image.source == data.object.preview, 'preview-not-selected': image.source != data.object.preview }" ng-click="selected(image)" src="/app/videos/{{data.object.source}}/screenshots/{{image.source}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger"  ng-click="reset()">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </span><span translate="PAGE.RESET" class="nopadding"></span>
                </button>
                <button ng-disabled="data.$invalid && !IsValid()" type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </span><span translate="PAGE.CREATE" class="nopadding"></span>
                </button>
                </div>
            </div>

               </div>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the controller with the relevant code in it that causes the problem.

Comment: See [mcve] . There isn't enough shown for us to reproduce or properly analyze problem. Show all relevant code

Comment: Hi, @JimCote and charlietfl I've just added the controller and the view. Please let me know if you see anything weird. This is my first angularjs app so besides my issue, maybe you have some best practices to share with me that I'm not following here.

Comment: You are setting `$scope.data.object = {...}` in your controller, then changing it to `$scope.data.object = []`.

Comment: Please only show code relevant to the actual problem. We don't need to wade through non related code. You went from one extreme of not enough code to the other of too much

Comment: @JimCote I remove it, but it didn't work. Actually, that was a quick fix i found to instanciate it in order to start using it. But it didn't work. I try to remove it again but I get the same error.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, I added everything because I have no idea where the issue is... the main sections are: in the view the submit button that is calling the IsValid function. and the same function in the controller and the description of tje $scope variable

Comment: You really need to learn how to debug Javascript in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for so useful advice.

Comment: I debugged and I saw that the $scope variable change from having all the properties I needed to be "FormController" and its remove all the values

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The issue was that the parameter I was using in the controller has the same name to de form I was using in the view. After I change the form name, the issue was fixed.